# nested MySQL JOIN does not produce wanted column

Tags: mysql, nested

I am using a nested JOIN and am expecting a column `BOARDING_LAST_EDIT` with ordered dates.

```
SELECT

OWNER.ID AS OWNER_ID,
OWNER.FIRST_NAME,
OWNER.LAST_NAME,
OWNER.EMAIL

FROM OWNER

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT OWNER_ID, LAST_EDIT AS BOARDING_LAST_EDIT 
    FROM BOARDING 
    WHERE BOARDING.LAST_EDIT > '2017-01-01' 
    ORDER BY BOARDING.LAST_EDIT DESC
) AS BOARDING_NESTED_TABLE_ORDERED 
ON OWNER.ID = BOARDING_NESTED_TABLE_ORDERED.OWNER_ID

GROUP BY OWNER_ID

ORDER BY BOARDING_LAST_EDIT DESC
```

I am getting this returned:

**|OWNER_ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL|**

I want:
**|OWNER_ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL|BOARDING_LAST_EDIT|**

I was expecting that the nested "**AS BOARDING_LAST_EDIT**" would return the additional column `BOARDING_LAST_EDIT`

The whole point of the nested join - is to have the results grouped return in order of only the newest date first. Any dates below the newest date can be dropped.

If I join before sorting the table - I loose the ability to order in the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    OWNER.ID AS OWNER_ID,
    OWNER.FIRST_NAME,
    OWNER.LAST_NAME,
    OWNER.EMAIL,
    BOARDING_NESTED_TABLE_ORDERED.BOARDING_LAST_EDIT
FROM OWNER
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        OWNER_ID, 
        LAST_EDIT AS BOARDING_LAST_EDIT 
    FROM BOARDING 
    WHERE BOARDING.LAST_EDIT > '2017-01-01' 
    ORDER BY BOARDING.LAST_EDIT DESC
) BOARDING_NESTED_TABLE_ORDERED 
ON OWNER.ID = BOARDING_NESTED_TABLE_ORDERED.OWNER_ID
GROUP BY OWNER_ID
ORDER BY BOARDING_LAST_EDIT DESC
```

I've basically just added the pulling through of your required field to the initial select, referencing the JOINED dataset.

Comment: Yes! - that produces the results I want.  I thought that field lists needed to be part of the outer declarations. I simply want the column 'LAST_EDIT' to be in order of last known date - and then group them. I couldn't think of any other way to do this.  Does your statement seem like the proper way to achieve this? This query seems rather slow.

Comment: What type of field is "BOARDING_LAST_EDIT"? Is it something you could use "MAX()" on to retrieve just the highest of its value in the group per OWNER_ID?

Comment: It is 'timestamp'